# Change javascript to be static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following javascript code to give me drop down menus. I don't want it to drop down the menu. I want it to show all the menu by default what should I remove. Please help.

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function () {
        var obj = this;
        obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });
        obj.opts.on('click', function () {
            var opt = $(this);
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
        });
    },
    getValue: function () {
        return this.val;
    },
    getIndex: function () {
        return this.index;
    }
}
$(function () {
    var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));
    $(document).click(function () {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove

```
obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
       return false;
 });
```

### update

and add the class `active` by changing `var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );` into `var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd').addClass('active') );`

also if you don't want it to get hidden onclick of the document, remove the following as well.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    // all dropdowns
    $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: how to add? the class active?

Comment: brother you are awesomeeeeee :)